# ADAL JS Forced Logout in SPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure-active-directory, adal

I have written a SPA written in Angular, and am using Azure AD token based authentication, with Resources (like APIs) that are secured through bearer tokens. This allows the SPA to retrieve renewal tokens from Azure and continually stay logged in, as far as I know, forever.

I am using the ADAL JavaScript library for Angular to do this:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

Now there is a requirement to limit the users session to predetermined amount of time, lets say 15 hours.

I wrote a nice little service which stores a cookie upon login, every request it checks the date in the cookie and if they have exceeded their maximum session limit. This works fine if the user is continually uses the app, or closes the browser - but if they leave their browser open, the token will simply renew in the background and they remain logged in.

I am now trying to solve this using a silent sign out solution. Meaning, I would like the user to be forced to the Secure Sign in Page once their session has expired.

This seems like it would be a common scenario, but I can not seem to figure out how to achieve it, as ADAL uses an iFrame in the background. I thought about using a timer/interval, but that seems hokey.

Just FYI I am using the adalAuthenticationService.logout() per my below code sample. I have also tried clearing the session cache, which works - but ADAL will silently refresh the token. I also tried setting the redirectUri location to a non authenticated page, but still, it will only redirect there if the user takes action. If the browser simply remains open, the token will just reset itself.

```
    var maxTime = 15; // hours allowed in session

    // event to fire check; maybe this can be different, and is my problem?
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $scope.checkLogoutCookie();
    });
    $scope.logout = function() {
        adalAuthenticationService.logout();
    };
    function setCookie(c) {} // implementation details don't matter....
    function getCookie(c) {} // implementation details don't matter....
    $scope.checkLogoutCookie = function () {
        var lastLogin = getCookie("lastLogin");
        var loginDate = new Date();
        if (lastLogin === "") { // is empty
            setCookie("lastLogin", loginDate, 365);
        } else {
            var lastDate = new Date(lastLogin);
            var hours = Math.abs(lastDate - loginDate) / 36e5;
            if (hours > maxTime) {
                setCookie("lastLogin", "", 0);
                $scope.logout();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wrote a nice little service which stores a cookie upon login, every request it checks the date in the cookie and if they have exceeded their maximum session limit. This works fine if the user is continually uses the app, or closes the browser - but if they leave their browser open, the token will simply renew in the background and they remain logged in.

Based on the description, it seems that the code check the date is executed after the HTTP request interceptor of adal-angular.js.

If it is possible, you need to implement this function before the interceptor of ADAL library.

If it is impossible, you can change the business logic to 
check whether the app session is not expired before acquiring the token. For this, we need to change the source code of the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript.

For example, you can change the the HTTP request interceptor of **adal-angular.js** used to insert the code to check the whether your app is in the session. Here is the code of interceptor for your reference:

```
AdalModule.factory('ProtectedResourceInterceptor', ['adalAuthenticationService', '$q', '$rootScope', '$templateCache', function (authService, $q, $rootScope, $templateCache) {

    return {
        request: function (config) {
            if (config) {

                config.headers = config.headers || {};

                // if the request can be served via templateCache, no need to token
                if ($templateCache.get(config.url)) return config;

                var resource = authService.getResourceForEndpoint(config.url);
                authService.verbose('Url: ' + config.url + ' maps to resource: ' + resource);
                if (resource === null) {
                    return config;
                }
//add/modify the code here
                var tokenStored = authService.getCachedToken(resource);
                if (tokenStored) {
                    authService.info('Token is available for this url ' + config.url);
                    // check endpoint mapping if provided
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + tokenStored;
                    return config;
                }
                else {
                    // Cancel request if login is starting
                    if (authService.loginInProgress()) {
                        if (authService.config.popUp) {
                            authService.info('Url: ' + config.url + ' will be loaded after login is successful');
                            var delayedRequest = $q.defer();
                            $rootScope.$on('adal:loginSuccess', function (event, token) {
                                if (token) {
                                    authService.info('Login completed, sending request for ' + config.url);
                                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + tokenStored;
                                    delayedRequest.resolve(config);
                                }
                            });
                            return delayedRequest.promise;
                        }
                        else {
                            authService.info('login is in progress.');
                            config.data = 'login in progress, cancelling the request for ' + config.url;
                            return $q.reject(config);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // delayed request to return after iframe completes
                        var delayedRequest = $q.defer();
                        authService.acquireToken(resource).then(function (token) {
                            authService.verbose('Token is available');
                            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
                            delayedRequest.resolve(config);
                        }, function (error) {
                            config.data = error;
                            delayedRequest.reject(config);
                        });

                        return delayedRequest.promise;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            authService.info('Getting error in the response: ' + JSON.stringify(rejection));
            if (rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    var resource = authService.getResourceForEndpoint(rejection.config.url);
                    authService.clearCacheForResource(resource);
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('adal:notAuthorized', rejection, resource);
                }
                else {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('adal:errorResponse', rejection);
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `adalAuthenticationService`'s method `logOut()`. I think the issue is that you have used `logout()` incorrectly. Please note the uppercase of `o` in the `logout()` method.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17680085)

Comment: Yes!. Thanks for the note. I have changed my answer according to the rule.